# mssql pdo with hhvm

Tags: sql-server, laravel, hhvm

I've installed nginx and hhvm on a ubuntu machine. I also need the sybase or mssql pdo driver to make Laravel 5 use mssql.

But what do I need to do to install it? I'm pretty sure `php5-sybase` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the sybase extension isn't available for HHVM yet. http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/sybase.installation.php